# Adding Google Maps Android API V2 fail with Gradle: UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I want to put Google Maps Android API V2 on my project but I have an issue.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.****.android.****"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">

        <activity
            android:name="com.****.android.****.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".fragmentmodule.AppMainTabActivity"
            android:label="activity_main"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".PDFActivity"
            android:label="activity_pdf"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBfD***********QaNXISLpWaku"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

myactivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Note"
                android:id="@+id/details_button_note"/>

        <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Localisation"
                android:id="@+id/details_button_location"/>

        <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Mail"
                android:id="@+id/details_button_mail"/>

        <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Favori"
                android:id="@+id/details_button_favori"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Organisme"
                android:id="@+id/details_textView_organisme"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/blueEmp"
                android:textSize="14dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Date d'expiration :"
                    android:id="@+id/details_textViewBVF_date"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="30/10/88 à 3h00"
                    android:id="@+id/details_textView_date"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Departement :"
                    android:id="@+id/details_textViewBF_dpt"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                    android:textColor="@color/gris_emp"
                    android:textSize="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="75"
                    android:id="@+id/details_textView_dpt"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/gris_emp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="false">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/> <!-- This line doesn't works -->

        <WebView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/details_webview"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ouvrir le PDF"
                android:id="@+id/details_button_pdf"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:minWidth="200dp"
                android:minHeight="100dp"/>

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/details_edittext_note"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**An error occurred**

```
Gradle: Error while executing dx command
Gradle: UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Gradle: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatHoneycomb;
Gradle: at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
Gradle: at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
Gradle: at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:490)
Gradle: 1 error; aborting
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':****:dexDebug'.
```

### I have installed (with SDK Manager) the last version of :

- Android Support Repository
- Android Support Library
- Google Play Services
- Google Repository

Someone know why I have this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

See, you are supporting Pre-Honeycomb versions as well. Your manifest says 8-16. but your fragment says "class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

Change it to

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/mapFrag" 
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_weight="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: I have an error with your code too. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" on path: /data/app/com.****.android.******-1.apk

Comment: with SupportMapFragment you have to add 
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
to build.gradle